# Use OneDrive and iCloud Drive to back up the same source

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization

I have OneDrive on my Mac because I want to have full interaction and integration with Office 365. The downside to this is that anything backed up into OneDrive will not back up into iCloud.

Is there a way to have both iCloud and OneDrive back up the same source? I would say using hardlinks, but they are no longer viable in the APFS format.

I would remove OneDrive if Auto Saving was possible though Office without using OneDrive.

Comment: Just thinking out aloud here, but can I suggest it may be worth explaining *why* you want to be able to have your Office files also synced to iCloud? The reasons for doing this are not *obvious* and while we don't necessarily need to understand *why* you're asking a question, in this case it may help ensure you get better answers or suggestions to help you achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: What do you mean by backup? Do you have your Office files within OneDrive and want to regularly copy them to iCloud Drive? Should this be a one-way copy or a bidirectional sync?