# Make iCloud drive and Microsoft OneDrive the same folder on Windows 11 PC

Tags: icloud, backup

I found a similar post here, but not much help
[Use OneDrive and iCloud Drive to back up the same source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367503/use-onedrive-and-icloud-drive-to-back-up-the-same-source)

On my windows 11 pc, I currently have moved my iCloud folder from C:\Users\joelj\iCloudDrive to E:\iCloud\iCloud Drive and its currently downloading all the files to that location. I achieved this by following the steps in How to Change the iCloud Drive Folder Location on Windows 10 (https://www.guidingtech.com/change-icloud-drive-folder-location-windows-10/)

Now my OneDrive location is currently in C:\Users\joelj\OneDrive

I would like my OneDrive to also point to E:\iCloud\iCloud Drive.

I am planning to follow the steps in below website for configuring both the iCloud and OneDrive to point to the same folder. However instead of moving the actual folder, I am thinking of changing the OneDrive folder to iCloud Drive
How to Move Your OneDrive Folder (https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/move-onedrive-folder)

Could someone please advice if its recommended for both iCloud and OneDrive to point to the same folder? If so, what is the best way to go about it.

**Update:**
On my windows 11 pc, I was able to move my OneDrive to the E:\iCloud\iCloud Drive\Desktop\OneDrive

Now all my files are backed up in OneDrive successfully(since the files were already in OneDrive online, it just had to be downloaded onto my windows 11 pc, which was fast with my 400mbps download speed), however iCloud is taking a long time to upload the 200GB worth of files.

My PC is pretty good, with 400mbps download and 21mbps upload via hardwired ethernet.. sadly the upload is only 21mbps as I don't have fiber :(

- Windows 11 Pro
- Alienware Aurora R8
- Core i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz
- Nvidia RTX 2080Ti
- 32GB Ram
- 2TB NVMe Main Internal Drive
- 1TB Internal Sata SSD (this 1TB Sata SSD is the one I am using as my iCloud Drive and OneDrive. Both the iCloud Drive and the OneDrive are being synced in this path E:\iCloud\iCloud Drive\Desktop\OneDrive)
- 1TB Internal Sata SSD (this 1TB Sata SSD has a static backup/dump of my OneDrive folder, the rest is free space)

Already some of the files have started to appear under OneDrive folder in icloud.com when I check on my web browser, although it took a few days for the OneDrive folder to appear in icloud.com. However these files are not visible as of now, on any of my apple devices yet, the OneDrive folder isnt even visible on any of my apply devices yet.

**Kindly Note:**
The reason I would like the files to be backed up to OneDrive and iCloud, is for Microsoft office files to AutoSave and also make use of the advantages of OneDrive on Windows like filesharing... likewise the iCloud sync is used to access the files on my Apple Devices like my Macbook Pro and iPhone.

Also another advantage is to have two redundant cloud backups, one on iCloud and one on OneDrive as a fail safe.

**Question:**
I remember the last time I had to upload a good chunk of files over twenty GB to icloud it probably took a month. I forgot about the upload and after several months I realized the files were synced. Since this is two hundred GB of files to be uploaded to iCloud, should I do the same with this? Let it just upload in the background forever and hope that it syncs eventually? Or is there a better way to track this icloud upload?

Comment: it may be *possible* to do, would I *recommend it?* nope. Two competing sync utilities syncing the same folder is not a great idea **ESPECIALLY** on Win11. I've been supporting Win and Mac for 30+ years and I *never, ever* install the new version of Windows until it has been out at least a year.